# Edit Distance of a large string efficiently

Tags: c, edit, distance

Is there any other algorithm apart from the usual dynamic programming approach which takes O(n*m) time which takes less time than this? String input sizes can be atmost (100000) each. The usual algorithm do not work...Are more efficient algorithm available?

Comment: What is the usual dynamic programming approach? What type of edit distance are you looking for? What are m and n? What have you tried?

Comment: @genisage Obvious approach is dp one....see this....
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/

Comment: If your allowed edits are insertion deletion and substitution, you might try the [levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) but if you want a non-standard algorithm tailored to your problem, you'll need to give more specifics/constraints.

Comment: [Navarro](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.3112&rep=rep1&type=pdf) cites a few algorithms that improve over the vanilla edit-distance algorithm (Wagner-Fischer). I remember one by Ukkonen that takes time O(ns), IIRC, where s is an upper bound (so distances greater than s are reported as s), but I can't find the PDF right now.

Comment: @larsmans that optimization is easy.  Don't look at matrix entries more than s units from the diagonal.

Comment: @RobNeuhaus I was mistaken, Ukkonen's algorithm runs in O(s²) time where s is the bound. Of course, if the bound is relative to (linear in) the input length, that only buys you a constant factor.